# How to store a global array reference but initialise values later in some method of implementation file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I want to keep a reference to array in interface like:

```
@interface
{
   float myArray[];
}
@end
```

and then use it in my implementation file like:

```
@implementation

-(void)someMethodToFillValuesInArray
{
  myArray = { 10.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f };
}

-(void)someMethodToUseArray
{
   float sum = myArray[0] + myArray[1];
}

@end
```

However, XCode throws syntax errors and I can't compile.

I am failing to understand the syntax and I tried a lot of ways but was unable to get it going. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Title says "...store global array reference...", but in the code example you are trying to declare instance varible myArray.

Comment: Talking about instance variable as global reference, means the global reference with regards to any method in its implementation file.

Comment: You need to use pointer to `float` instead of the array. Initialize it when you need with `malloc`. When you are done with the array (in `dealloc` for example) call `free`.

Comment: What you want to do and why you cannot use singleton if you must insist upon global access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static initialiser at the time when array is declared not after it is declared.

It is permitted as you are initialising at the time of its declaration

```
float myArray = { 10.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f };
```

Else you should declared array with length as follows in your interface

```
float    *myArray;
```

and use it in you implementation file as follows

To dynamically allocate space, use calls to malloc passing in the total number of bytes to allocate

```
int size = 3;    // This size can be whatever you set during runtime or compile time
myArray = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*size);
myArray[0] = 1.0;
myArray[1] = 2.0;
myArray[2] = 3.0;
```

but since manually allocated a certain amount of memory for array, you are responsible for freeing it once you are done with it. Use free(myArray) to free the allocated memory.

Comment: I want to initialise the array somewhere later in code. How can I do that and still maintain a global reference in the interface file ?

Comment: You can with above mentioned approach provided that an array's length is given.

Comment: Did you specify the length?

Comment: I missed adding a semicolon to the above myArray declaration.

Comment: Please refer the answer again.

Comment: ok, its working for known length ahead of time. But my actual question is to keep a reference to an array of unknown length. How can I do this ?

Comment: You cannot use primitive type array for unknown length unless it is statically initialised, instead you should use NSArray or NSMutableArray of Objective C and convert those primitive float values to respective wrapper object and store it in NSArray.

Comment: NSMutableArray is a good way. However, there is a lot of overhead in creating mutableArrays and then the instances of NSNumber(s) within the arrays to hold float values. Basically I want to transfer large amount of float data per frame (i.e. 60 times a second ) to opengl and converting local float arrays from NSMutableArrays will slow down the render loop too much.

Comment: refer the answer again.

Comment: There is a problem with your answer it should be float * myArray = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*3); You have used int at certain places which is not proper.